# when type something then new window open with tree view

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## a.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (500, 330)


con = lite.connect('demo.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()

class GroupScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Group(App):
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `groups` order by group_id asc")
    #rows = cur.fetchall()

    rows = [(1, 'Branch/Dividions', ''), (2, 'Capital Account', 'Reserve & Surplus')]

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('a.kv')
        return self.root



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## a.kv

```
GroupScreen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Group'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupName

        Label:
            text: 'Leadger No.'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupCode

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'

        Label:

        Label:



<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False


<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have a.py and a.kv file.
 1. when i type any keyword in Test textBox then new window should be open with treeview structure.
 2. when select any value from treeview then it will be place in textbox which should be disable for manual typing.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example use *on_text* event to invoke a *popup* widget containing a *treeview* and a cancel button. on_text event will be dispatched whenever the text changes.

## Example

### main.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

# Window.size = (500, 330)

# con = lite.connect('demo.db')
# con.text_factory = str
# cur = con.cursor()


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


tree = [{'node_id': 'Capital Account',
         'children': [{'node_id': 'Reserves & Surplus',
                       'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1',
                                     'children': [{'node_id': '1.1.1.1',
                                                   'children': []}]},
                                    {'node_id': '1.1.2',
                                     'children': []},
                                    {'node_id': '1.1.3',
                                     'children': []}]},
                       {'node_id': '1.2',
                        'children': []}]},
        {'node_id': 'Current Assests',
         'children': []}]


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text="Branch/Divisions"),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `groups` order by group_id asc")
    #rows = cur.fetchall()

    rows = [(1, 'Branch/Dividions', ''), (2, 'Capital Account', 'Reserve & Surplus')]

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.groupName.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    id: treeview
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Groups"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            id: treeview
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Close"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    groupName: groupName

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Group'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupName
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Leadger No.'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupCode

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'

        Label:

        Label:
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]